# How can I place two selects side by side and have them pull-left and pull-right respectively with Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 selects side by side both getting 6 columns each.

[image: With Padding]

In order to get them to look correctly I have removed the left padding from the left select and the right from the right.

Using classes pull-left and pull-right does not have any effect.

[image: side by side]

However when I decrease the view port size it no longer looks correct.

[image: Smaller screen size]

What is the best way to achieve what I need?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Min Year:</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="minYear" ng-options="" required>
            <option value="">Min</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Max Year:</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="maxYear" ng-options="" required>
            <option value="">Max</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

thank.

Comment: What does "what I need" look like? Your request is confusing; the screenshot saying "does not have any effect" is clearly different from the original, and the one saying "decrease the view port size" is clearly larger than the others.

Comment: Thats because they stack on a smaller screen.

Answer (score 0):

for the decrement of size you shold add the correct col for `sm and xs`

```
div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <label>Min Year:</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="minYear" ng-options="" required>
        <option value="">Min</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <label>Max Year:</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="maxYear" ng-options="" required>
        <option value="">Max</option>
    </select>
 </div>
</div>
```